# Using jQuery, how can i run this animation more than once?

Tags: jquery, animation

This is my complete code. When I view this example on the demo site (listed below) It works, but when I use it on  my site, it only animates once and clicking on the DIV doesn't run the animation again. I see its opacity change, but it doesn't re-animate. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

  <head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <style>

      @keyframes my-animation {        
        from {
          opacity : 0;
          left : -500px;
        }
        to {
          opacity : 1;
          left : 0;
        }      
      }

      .run-animation {
        position: relative;
        animation: my-animation 2s ease;
      }

      #logo {
        text-align: center; 
        font-family : Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
      }

    </style>

    <script>

    <!--- jQquery check to see if the document is ready --->
    <!--- --------------------------------------------- --->
      $(document).ready(

        function(){

            // retrieve the element
           var element = $("#logo");

          // reset the transition by...
          element.click( function() {
              element.removeClass("run-animation")
              element.css("opacity", ".5");
              element.addClass("run-animation");
          });
        }
      );

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="logo" class="run-animation">
      Fancy Text
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the site I got it from:
http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add respective vendor prefixes as Chris Coyier has mentioned right at the begining. If you are viewing it on chrome you will be able to see the animation in the following fiddle where i have used `-webkit-` for the vendor prefix

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kszarz1z/)**

Comment: I was originally using <script src="prefixfree.min.js"></script> which I forgot to include. I have put it back in so the prefixes should not be necessary. But I looked at your fiddle page and I don't see it working there either. Putting the prefix in still does not make it work for me.